# I am getting IntegrityError in Django

Tags: django-rest-framework

null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, 10000, 11200, null).

this is my models.py

id =models.CharField(max_length=6, primary_key = True, editable=False, unique=True)
user =  models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

I was trying to return a Json Response

Answer (score 0):

insert null = True in your id model, this will correct the integrity error.

Answer (score 0):

You said you were trying to return a JSON response; was this saved in some way or another?

This error indicates that nothing is passed to the user field on save. Hence, you need to give the user field a user instance before saving. Can we see what you are trying to do in order to know how to fix the problem?